# incomplete representation of ctrl+c functionality of terminals in python code

Tags: python, subprocess, ros, popen, rosbag

I have an application that I execute in terminal by through the following command:

```
rosbag record -O /home/user/some_address/file /topic
```

which makes a `file.bag.active` in the above address and basically record some information inside it.

After a while by pressing ctrl+c in the terminal the `file.bag.active` changes to `file.bag` and will be ready to be read by another application.

Yet, I want to make this sequence done by a python script for which the best way seems doing the following:

```
import subprocess, shlex

command = "rosbag record -O /home/user/some_address/file /topic"
command = shlex.split(command)
self.proc = subprocess.Popen(command)
```

where another part of the script that is meant to represent the ctrl+c function is:

```
self.proc.send_signal(subprocess.signal.SIGINT)
```

However, in this case the `file.bag.active` file doesn't change to `file.bag`, and I am not sure what else I can do or add to this code that will do so.

What I noticed in addition was that if I add a pdb.set_trace() and press ctrl+c inside it when it is invoked I get the result I look for which I can't explain why or how I can represent such functionality in an automatic code.

Does anyone know a workaround for it?

Comment: (Tangentially, you don't really need `shlex()` here; your command is simple and static. `self.proc = subprocess.Popen(['rosbag', 'record', '-O', '/home/user/some_address/file', '/topic'])`.)

Comment: @tripleee true, it's just a modified copy of another example that I had used. I have also tried without it but the outcome was the same.

Answer (score 0):

Got an answer [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/367930/stopping-rosbag-record-from-script/), that is:

```
import subprocess, shlex, psutil
command = "rosbag record -O subset /camera/depth/image_raw /camera/rgb/image_raw /joy /mobile_base/sensors/imu_data_raw"
command = shlex.split(command)
rosbag_proc = subprocess.Popen(command)
```

and for the ctrl+c functionality:

```
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    if "record" in proc.name() and set(command[2:]).issubset(proc.cmdline()):
        proc.send_signal(subprocess.signal.SIGINT)

rosbag_proc.send_signal(subprocess.signal.SIGINT)
```